# Add frame with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i trying to make web page which i can use in ebay, it includes html and bootstrap. here my codes

```
<style>
body
{
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
}   
.yazi
{
    font-size: 20px;  
    color: #0A17FD;  
}
.ysi
{
   font-size: 20px;
   color:#F94141;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-9 column">
<img src="logo.png" height="90" width="310">  <!--LOGO-->
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 column ysi"> 
asdasdad@gmail.com <br>0110101010 <br>place
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12 column ysi"> 
 <hr>
</div>
</div>
<br><div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 column yazi"><h3>PRODUCT TİTLE</h3> 
<br><br>

<ul>
<li>product features product features product features</li>     
<li>product features product features product features</li> 
<li>product features product features product features</li>   
<li>product features product features product features</li>   
<li>product features product features product features</li>   
<li>product features product features product features</li>   
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 column">
<img src="productpic.jpg" height="600" width="577" class="img-responsive"><!-- Product pic -->
</div>                                                                        
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 column yazi">
<br><br>
<ul>
<li>explanations explanations explanations explanations</li>  
<li>explanations explanations explanations explanations</li>  
<li>explanations explanations explanations explanations</li>   
<li>explanations explanations explanations explanations</li>   
<li>explanations explanations explanations explanations</li>   
<li>explanations explanations explanations explanations</li>  `
</ul>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

it works , my question is ; i need to add frame which include product features. and add other frame which include expalanations. lastly , i need to add other frame which  include whole page. How can i do this? thank you

Comment: Please use jsfiddle for code sharing.

Comment: Here is ; https://jsfiddle.net/p7u4z8jg/